# EAR compiled with java 11 deployment error

Tags: java, wildfly, ear, java-11

Have an EAR application compiled with java 11.
 When deployed to Wildfly 14 returns the following error:

```
Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ef' defined in class path resource [application-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [application-context.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'driverClassName' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver]

...

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'driverClassName' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver]
    at deployment.test-1.0.ear//org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:121)
```

The same application **compiled with Java 8 deploys without problems** (Actually it started as a java 8 application). So it does not seem to be an issue with the driver itself.

This is the **module.xml** in the Wildfly path modules/system/layers/base/com/oracle/main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.5" name="com.oracle">
  <resources>
    <resource-root path="ojdbc6.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <dependencies>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
    <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
  </dependencies>
</module>
```

What is the best way to change the EAR application so when compiled with java 11 will depoy correctly?

Comment: there is no version 14 in java please be sure about the version of java  may be you  are referring to java 1.4 ??

Comment: What is the version of `ojdbc` JAR that you are using?

Comment: a typo error in the title, just rectified to java 11.

Comment: added more info, ojdbc 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ojdbc6` driver does not support Java 11. Only `ojdbc8` driver with database 18.3 is fully supporting Java 11, as per [What are the Oracle JDBC releases versus JDK versions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-faq-090281.html#01_03_1).

Either upgrade the driver (and potentially the database) or keep using Java 8.

Comment: I have upgraded/deployed the driver (and its reference within module.xml). yet, getting the same error. I see (before the error) some warnings: "Class Path entry commons-logging-1.2.jardoes not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference." Could be that from java 9 with modules, the EAR is not well structured? No clue with that.

Comment: Your dependencies are not supporting Java 11. Find a newer version that supports it or replace the dependency with alternative library that does.

Comment: thanks for the help, i will test and mark the question as answered in few days